# $F(u,v) = F(u) \iff v = f(u)$ for some $f\in F[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that: $F(u,v) = F(u) \iff v = f(u)$ for some $f\in F[X]$ where $F$ is a field and $F(u)$ denotes the smallest field containing $F$ and $u$.

I can show the result if $u$ is algebraic over $F$ since then $F(u) = \{a_0+...+a_{n-1}u^{n-1}: a_i\in F\}$. However I cannot prove it for when $u$ is transcendental over $F$, since then we can only say that $F(u) = \{f(u)g^{-1}(u): f,g \in F[X]\}$. So how can I show the result?

Comment: Have you answered this yourself? If $u$ is transcendental and $v=u^{-1}$ then surely it's impossible?

Comment: What is impossible?

Comment: I think there should be some hypothesis like $u$ is algebraic or that $F(u)$ is a finite extension of $F$.

Comment: I think so as well, perhaps a mistake in the question

Answer (score 0):

With $u$ transcendental and $v=u^{-1}$ we would (if the statement is true) have $u^{-1}=f(u)$ for some polynomial $f$. That is, $1=uf(u)$ in the polynomial ring $F[u]$, a contradiction.